# How to keep track of previous index in a for loop? (rust)

Tags: loops, rust

I'm trying to see how many numbers are bigger than the previous number in a vector. This is my code so far:

```
fn get_result(depths: &Vec<u32>) { 
    let mut result: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    for (idx,num) in depths.iter().enumerate() { 
        if depths[idx - 1] > depths[idx] { 
            result.push(depths[idx]);
    }
    
}
println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

When I run this, it gives me the following error:

```
thread main panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow'
```

I know that this is caused by the depths[idx - 1], but I'm not entirely sure how to keep track of the previous index.

Comment: `idx - 1` is invalid when `idx` is a `usize` with value `0`. You could just do `for idx in 1..depths.len()`

Comment: @DenysSéguret That worked! I had tried to add "&& idx != 0" to the if statement, but it hadn't worked for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: Another solution: `if depths[idx.saturating_sub(1)] > depths[idx]`

Comment: Aaah, the advent of code strikes again :D

Comment: Testing if `idx != 0` should work too, but it should be done _before_ the substraction: `idx != 0 && depths[idx - 1] > depths[idx]` and not `depths[idx - 1] > depths[idx] && idx != 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also `zip` using some iterators to check the pairs:

```rust
for (a, b) in depths.iter().zip(depths.iter().skip(1)) {
    if a < b {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`idx - 1` is invalid when `idx` is a `usize` with value `0`.

You have nothing to compare to for the first element. So you should start the iteration at `1`:

```rust
for idx in 1..depths.len() {
   if depths[idx - 1] > depths[idx] { 
       result.push(depths[idx]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Note: you could also use `for (idx,num) in depths.iter().enumerate().skip(1)`, and use `num` instead of `depths[idx]` but it looks dirty to me to combine `enumerate` with looking at the previous item. The good old index based loop is the most obvious solution here.